# combining two numpy arrays of different dtype to a structured array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy float array and an int array of the same length. I would like to concatenate them such that the output has the [composite dtype `(float, int)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.rec.html). `column_stack`ing them together just yields a `float64` array:

```py
import numpy

a = numpy.random.rand(5)
b = numpy.random.randint(0, 100, 5)

ab = numpy.column_stack([a, b])
print(ab.dtype)
```

```
float64
```

Any hints?

Comment: Define a composite dtype, make a `np.zeros(...)` from it, and assign the respective fields.  Your link has more information on creating structured arrays.  I don't think it mentions `column_stack`.

Comment: If using Pandas isn't an issue then could simply do `pd.DataFrame({'a':a, 'b':b})` - should preserve dtypes

Comment: `np.rec.fromarrays([a,b])` if a recarray is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 'blank' array:

```
In [391]: dt = np.dtype('f,i')                                                                 
In [392]: arr = np.zeros(5, dtype=dt)                                                          
In [393]: arr                                                                                  
Out[393]: 
array([(0., 0), (0., 0), (0., 0), (0., 0), (0., 0)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

fill it:

```
In [394]: arr['f0']=np.random.rand(5)                                                          
In [396]: arr['f1']=np.random.randint(0,100,5)                                                 
In [397]: arr                                                                                  
Out[397]: 
array([(0.40140057, 75), (0.93731374, 99), (0.6226782 , 48),
       (0.01068745, 68), (0.19197434, 53)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

There are recfunctions that can be used as well, but it's good to know (and understand) this basic approach.